# How to disable Create Project permission for users by default in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

I am using the Omnibus **GitLab CE** system with LDAP authentication.

Because of LDAP authentication, anyone in my company can sign in to GitLab and a new GitLab user account associated with this user is created (according to my understanding).

I want to modify it so that **by default this new user** (who can automatically sign in based on his LDAP credentials) **cannot create new projects**.

Then, I as the admin, will probably handle most new project creation.

I might give the Create Project permission to a few special users.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### In newer versions of GitLab >= v7.8 …

This is not a setting in `config/gitlab.yml` but rather in the *GUI* for admins.

Simply navigate to `https://___[your GitLab URL]___/admin/application_settings/general#js-account-settings`, and set *Default projects limit* to **`0`**.

You can then access individual users's project limit at `https://___[your GitLab URL]___/admin/users`.

See [GitLab's update docs](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/update/7.7-to-7.8.md#5-update-config-files) for more settings changed between v7.7 and v7.8.

```
git diff origin/7-7-stable:config/gitlab.yml.example origin/7-8-stable:config/gitlab.yml.example
```

Answer (score 4):

**For all new users:**

Refer to `Nick Merrill` answer.

**For all existing users:**

This is the best and quick method to make changes to projects limits:

```
$ gitlab-rails runner "User.where(projects_limit: 10).each { |u| u.projects_limit = 0; u.save }"
```

Answer (score 3):

( **Update:**  This applies to versions <= 7.7:)

The default permissions are set in `gitlab.yml`

In omnibus, that is `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/gitlab.yml`

Look for

```
## User settings
default_projects_limit: 10
# default_can_create_group: false  # default: true
```

Setting default_projects_limit to zero, and default_can_create_group to false may be what you want.
Then an admin can change the limits for individual users.

**Update:**

This setting was included in the admin GUI in version 7.8 (see answer by @Nick M). At least with Omnibus on Centos7 an upgrade retains the setting.

Note that the setting `default_can_create_group` is still in `gitlab.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my quick-and-dirty Python script which you can use in case you **already have some users created** and want to **change all your existing users to make them unable to create projects on their own**:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
import json

gitlab_url = "https://<your_gitlab_host_and_domain>/api/v3"
headers = {'PRIVATE-TOKEN': '<private_token_of_a_user_with_admin_rights>'}

def set_user_projects_limit_to_zero (user):
    user_id = str(user['id'])
    put = requests.put(gitlab_url + "/users/" + user_id + "?projects_limit=0", headers=headers)
    if put.status_code != 200:
        print "!!! change failed with user id=%s, status code=%s" % (user_id, put.status_code)
        exit(1)
    else:
        print "user with id=%s changed!" % user_id

users_processed = 0
page_no = 1
total_pages = 1
print "processing 1st page of users..."
while page_no <= total_pages:
    users = requests.get(gitlab_url + "/users?page=" + str(page_no), headers=headers)
    total_pages = int(users.headers['X-Total-Pages'])
    for user in users.json():
        set_user_projects_limit_to_zero(user)
        users_processed = users_processed + 1
    print "processed page %s/%s..." % (page_no, total_pages)
    page_no = page_no + 1
print "no of processed users=%s" % users_processed
```

Tested & working with GitLab CE 8.4.1 052b38d, YMMV.